# Clojure - Making AJAX request doesn't return JSON

Tags: json, ajax, clojure, ring

I've got a website that I'm the process of developing, the backend route which isn't working is /login with the compojure route as:

```
 (POST login "/" [] check-admin-before-logging)
```

This is what the check-admin-before-logging function does:

```
(defn redirect-admin-to-page
  []
  (-> (response/redirect "/admin/home")
      (assoc :body "logging you in...")
      (assoc :cookies {:token (token/sign-token)})))

;; function that checks whether credentials are in fact valid.
;; check-admin is a db func which compares hashed pswd with input.
(defn check-admin-before-logging-in
  [request]
  (let [username (:username (:params request))
        password (:password (:params request))]
    (if (check-admin username password)
      (redirect-admin-to-page username)
      (str "username : " username " and password " password " is not valid.\n" request))))
```

For the moment it just returns a string, as for testing purposes.

and for the app I have wrapped it in the following middleware:

```
(def app
  (-> all-routes
      (wrap-defaults (assoc-in site-defaults [:security :anti-forgery] false))
      (wrap-json-body)
      ;; (wrap-json-params)
      (wrap-json-response)
))
```

Now when I make an AJAX request with the following on the frontend:

```
(defn submit
  []
  (let [username *grabbed from input field...*
        password *grabbed from input field...*]
     (POST "/login" {:params {:username username :password password}})))
```

But the problem arises when I actually click the button [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJlr2.png). The console shows the result of the post request itself, with :params being empty and some mangled JSON in the :body key. If I was to try and include

```
(wrap-json-params)
```

within app, I would get nil in the :body and :params key. Moreover it seems there is a problem with the output, as cheshire has problems with parsing it. If I leave the ring-json library to the side and just have wrap-defaults over app, I just get this for the body key

```
:body #object[org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP 0x6ef9a9e1 HttpInputOverHTTP@6ef9a9e1]
```

My question is how do I change the json so that it is able to be understood by wrap-json-params or cheshire? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you returning from `check-admin-before-logging` ?

Comment: added it into the question

Comment: According to the docs for wrap-json-response:  _"Middleware that converts responses with a map or a vector for a body into a JSON response."_  Your body is a string, not a map or a vector. Try instead something like `... :body {:msg "logging you in..." }` and see if it helps.

Comment: Can you specify which library or framework are you using for making the AJAX request? I think that the request object that you receive in the method `check-admin-before-logging-in` will not have the params that you sent as it's direct child. You can try logging the request object in that method to understand the request schema